# Using StructureMap 3 in multiple ASP MVC projects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, structuremap

First lets start to describe my project architecture.
I have a asp.net mvc application called `Portal.Web` as startup project and multiple asp.net mvc applications which called `Plugin.XXX` (Plugin.News, Plugin.Cms, etc) and `Portal.Web` has references from all of these plugins.
I installed `StrcutureMap.Mvc5` for each one of these `Plugins`
As you know, when you install `StructureMap` a folder created called `DependencyResolution` and it contains some files, one of them is `IoC.cs` where you can initialize your container.
Now my problem is since all plugins has their own `IoC.cs`, it seems like they override each other containers so at the end I get this error :

```
No parameterless constructor defined for this object

// inner exception
No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'Portal.Plugins.Page.Interfaces.IPage'
There is no configuration specified for Portal.Plugins.Page.Interfaces.IPage
1.) new RouteController(*Default of IUnitOfWork*, *Default of IPage*)
2.) Portal.Web.Controllers.RouteController
3.) Instance of Portal.Web.Controllers.RouteController
4.) Container.GetInstance(Portal.Web.Controllers.RouteController)

There is no configuration specified for Portal.Plugins.Page.Interfaces.IPage
```

I could use ONE `IoC.cs` in `Portal.Web` project but I need to keep modularity and make Plugins independent as much as possible.
is there any way to keep plugins containers independent?

```
namespace Portal.Plugins.Account.DependencyResolution {
    using StructureMap;

    public static class IoC {
        public static IContainer Initialize() {
            return new Container(c =>
            {
                c.AddRegistry<DefaultRegistry>();
                c.For<IUnitOfWork>().LifecycleIs(new HttpContextLifecycle()).Use<AccountDbContext>();
                c.For<IAccount>().Use<AccountService>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Portal.Plugins.Cms.DependencyResolution {
    using StructureMap;

    public static class IoC {
        public static IContainer Initialize() {
            return new Container(c =>
            {
                c.AddRegistry<DefaultRegistry>();
                c.For<IUnitOfWork>().LifecycleIs(new HttpContextLifecycle()).Use<CmsDbContext>();
                c.For<IPage>().Use<PageService>();
                c.For<IMenu>().Use<MenuService>();
                c.For<IMedia>().Use<MediaService>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, couldn't you create a `DependencyResolution` class library that contains the `StructureMap.Mvc5` package that's then used throughout your plugins (this saves each of your plugins containing versions of `StructureMap.Mvc5`) and having a single reference to your `DependencyResolution` class library.

From here your individual plugins can then contain their own StructureMap registries, with more global registries being kept in the `DependencyResolution` class library.